# R -- how to ignore "Undefined" Columns in a dataset

Tags: r, bar-chart

## Data Set:

```
    V1          V2
1   Undefined   E1
2   Undefined   E2
3   Undefined   E3
4   Undefined   E4
5   Undefined   E5
6   Undefined   E6
7   Undefined   E7
8   Undefined   E8
```

## Question:

Above is a data set I'm trying to plot in R as a bar plot with another 4 datasets. The other 4 have actual data in V1, but this is dataset shows an undefined column. Can anyone help me write something that will allow R to ignore this dataset? For instance, if I had 4 datasets and 2 of them had an "Undefined" in them, R would ignore them and only plot 2 bins? Right now, R is plotting each Undefined as a bin with height of 1. If someone could help just get rid of this bin altogether, that'd be great.

## Here is a picture of my problem:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/27zx7oo.jpg

I would like to get rid of that 4th bar in each set altogether. Note that I can't set it to 0, as that is inaccurate. I would like to just avoid it altogether.

## Below is my code:

```
k_o_asdf <- read.delim("/Users/asdfman/Combinations/k_open/asdf.state", header=F)
m_o_asdf <- read.delim("/Users/asdfman/Combinations/m_open/asdf.state", header=F)
k_c_asdf <- read.delim("/Users/asdfman/Combinations/k_closed/asdf.state", header=F)
m_c_asdf <- read.delim("/Users/asdfman/Combinations/m_closed/asdf.state", header=F)

d <- data.frame(row.names=c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8"), K.Open = c(k_o_asdf$V1), M.Open = c(m_o_asdf$V1), K.Closed = c(k_c_asdfV1), M.Closed = c(m_c_asdf$V1))

d <- do.call(rbind, d)
barplot(d, beside = TRUE,ylim=c(0,2), legend.text = rownames(d), 
    args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty="n"))
```

Thanks very much for the help! If anything's unclear, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

You can use `row.names=paste0("E", 1:8)` instead of `row.names=c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8")`.

You can use `as.data.frame(t(d))` instead of `do.call(rbind, d)`.

To drop the "Undefined" column, try this:

```
d <- d[,!sapply(d, function(x)all(x=="Undefined"))]
```

before transposing.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand! I'm still a beginner at R, so thanks for the suggestions. Can you clarify where you place the d <- d[,!sapply(d, function(x)all(x=="Undefined"))]

I placed it right after my original d <- data.frame, and nothing changed. Do i need to substitute your changes in for it to work?

Comment: @BioinformaticsMan just before `d <- do.call(rbind, d)` (or `d <- as.data.frame(t(d))`, if you take my suggestion :-). It should work without changing anything else. Can you run `dput(head(d))` (after `d <- data.frame(...)`) and paste the output here?

Comment: structure(list(K.Open = c(0.117647058823529, 0.294117647058824, 
0.431372549019608, 0.117647058823529, 0.0588235294117647, 0.588235294117647
), M.Open = c(0.181818181818182, 0.181818181818182, 0.272727272727273, 
0.181818181818182, 0.181818181818182, 0.545454545454545), K.Closed = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5), M.Closed = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("K.Open", 
"M.Open", "K.Closed", "M.Closed"), row.names = c("E1", 
"E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @BioinformaticsMan I think the "Undefined" column is `M.Closed`, right? The problem is that this is a factor, not character. Can you try again using `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` before all `read.delim()` calls?

Comment: Wow. I am truly amazed haha! Thanks so much for the help. That worked! Now time to figure out how to do error bars :)

Comment: I would, but apparently I need 15 reputation haha.

Comment: Sorry for the sudden question again, but as I'm finalizing all these plots, I realize that the x-axis labels aren't showing up! I would like them to read E1, E2, E3, etc. but nothing shows. the x-axis label does show but not the individual marks.